# iOS when scroll hidden does not work

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

My goal that when  value is nil, a label should disappear.
     Before scrolling its working fine but when I scroll all label appear 
     and I don't know why?
      You can find below my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ORGContainerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ORGContainerCell"];
if(cell==nil){
cell = [[ORGContainerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ORGContainerCell"];
}
UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(293, 4, 27, 95)]; 
UIImageView *labelBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SUB TITLE BG.png"]];
Channel* getchannel = [categorieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section ];
NSMutableArray * getsub = getchannel.SubChannel;
if(getsub==nil){
  tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 490);
    headingLabel.hidden=YES;
    headingLabel.alpha = 0;
}else{
     headingLabel.alpha = 1;
    [cell addSubview:headingLabel];
Channel *val =  [getsub objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
headingLabel.text = val.ChannelName;
headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
headingLabel.tag = 10;
headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:14.0];
headingLabel.hidden = NO;
headingLabel.highlighted = YES;
headingLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
// headingLabel.lineBreakMode = YES;
headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
headingLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SUB TITLE BG.png"]];
// [headingLabel addSubview:labelBackground];
}
if(indexPath.section%2==0){
cell.strdatefromfirst = @"paire";
cell.backgroundColor =RGB(234, 234, 234);
}else{
cell.strdatefromfirst = @"impaire";
cell.backgroundColor =  RGB(196, 195, 194);  
}
NSDictionary *cellData = [self.sampleData objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
NSArray *articleData = [cellData objectForKey:@"articles"];
[cell setCollectionData:articleData];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because cells are reused once they scroll off-screen.  When cells are returned by the dequeue... method, the `headingLabel` that you previously added as a subview is not removed.  So you are seeing "old" headingLabels.  Personally, I would add `headingLabel` as a property to your `ORGContainerCell` subclass, and add it as a subview of your cell either in Storyboard/XIB or in init.  Then you will not need to alloc/init each time in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You will be able to change `headingLabel.xxx` to `cell.headingLabel.xxx`.  Also, I think it is unwise to adjust the frame of your tableView in the middle of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.